# Cookie not deleting or changing

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been working on a site that instructs my peers on how to use many of the customization features and software on their provided Windows 10 devices.

I am trying to add a dark theme to the site, and most of the work is there, but I am having trouble with using cookies to allow the theme selection persist throughout the website and multiple sessions. My issue is that visiting the webpage adds a cookie to enable the dark theme, but there should be no cookie initially.

My intent is for the website to default to the light theme when there is no cookie for the dark theme. In addition, if there is a cookie for the dark theme, when the user clicks the button for the light theme, the cookie for the dark theme should be deleted.

Through the process of making this website, I have been learning a lot, but I have been stumped by this issue. What am I doing wrong that causes the cookie to be stuck as `theme=dark`?

Script to restore the theme on page load:

```
function restoreTheme(){
    if(document.cookie="theme=dark") {
        darkTheme();
    } else {
        lightTheme();
    }
}
```

Script for changing theme:

```
function darkTheme() {
        document.body.style.setProperty("--sideNavBackground", "rgb(33,33,33)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--bodyBackgroundColor", "rgb(17,17,17)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--sideNavItemBackgroundHover", "rgb(64,64,64)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--bodyTextColor", "rgb(238,238,238)");
        document.cookie="theme=dark";
        document.cookie = "theme=light; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
    }
    function lightTheme() {
        document.body.style.setProperty("--sideNavBackground", "rgb(230,230,230)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--bodyBackgroundColor", "rgb(255,255,255)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--sideNavItemBackgroundHover", "rgb(199,199,199)");
        document.body.style.setProperty("--bodyTextColor", "rgb(17,17,17)");
        document.cookie="theme=light";
        document.cookie = "theme=dark; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";

    }
```

Buttons to change theme:

```
<form>
        <input name="theme" type="submit" class="theme_b" id="dark" onclick="darkTheme()" value="Dark Theme">
        <input name="theme" type="submit" class="theme_b" id="light" onclick="lightTheme()" value="Light Theme">
    </form>
```

For reference, here is a codepen of the (mostly) complete page: https://codepen.io/jackemery2001/pen/LrPvEJ/

Comment: Apart from the already mentioned issue of assignment vs comparison operator - document.cookie will likely _not_ contain `theme=dark` only. So log it to console to see what the value actually is first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Oops!

```
function restoreTheme(){
if(document.cookie="theme=dark") {
    darkTheme();
} else {
    lightTheme();
}
```

}

document.cookie="theme=dark" needs to be changed to document.cookie=="theme=dark"

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions of @Erich Brahmin and @CBroe, I was able to fix the issue.

I changed `function restoreTheme()` to

```
function restoreTheme() {
        var theme = getCookie("theme");
        if (theme=="dark") {
            //alert("dark");
            darkTheme();
        } else {
            //alert("light");
            lightTheme();
        }
    }
```

and added a script in the head for getCookie():

```
function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Simply changing document.cookie="theme=dark" to document.cookie=="theme=dark" was not fully effective because it only worked if there were no other cookies.

```
function restoreTheme(){
if(document.cookie="theme=dark") {
    darkTheme();
} else {
    lightTheme();
}
```

The working fix can be seen at https://codepen.io/jackemery2001/pen/LrPvEJ